# How to pass float as an argument at runtime in iOS

Tags: ios, parameters, floating-point

I'm really novice to iOS. I have set my `float` varibles and given values to them for calculating salary

ex:

```
float hra=34555.444;

float pf=1223.33;

float baseSalary=1222.33
```

and by using `Nsnumber` I can calculate the salary too.

I got the ans too. Now I would like to know how to pass these `float` as parameters which can be changed at runtime. I'm not using any UI so it should be hardcoded.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: To where you want to pass the float value(ie sending to another class or sending to a method in same class)

Comment: sending to a method in same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method in the class like this

```
-(void)methodName:(float)value{
//use value as your wish
}
```

to send value to this method

```
float hra=34555.444;

float pf=1223.33;

float baseSalary=1222.33
[self methodName: baseSalary];
```